# MSAL On-Behalf-Of (OBO) throws IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user

Tags: .net, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

Goal: MasterAPI to perform **On-Behalf-Of** flow to DownstreamAPI

Actors:

- Azure AD (Authentication Server)
- Public SPA (Client)
- MasterAPI (Resource Server)
- DownstreamAPI (Resource Server)

Flow:

- Public SPA client calls Azure `/authorize?scope=api://MasterAPI/access_as_user` using Authorization Code plus PKCE and receives an ID token
- Public SPA calls Azure `/token` and receives an access token
- Public SPA calls MasterAPI with the access token
- MasterAPI runs `IDownstreamWebAPI.CallWebApiForUserAsync()`.
- An exception is thrown: [conditional access](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access)

  - In my public SPA I add both scopes to MSAL.js but it still throws an exception.

MasterAPI:

```cs
await invoicingWebApi.CallWebApiForUserAsync<object, object>("DownstreamAPI", "",
options =>
{
  options.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post;
  options.RelativePath = $"test";
});
```

MasterAPI response:

```
IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent
```

Answer (score 0):

This error pops up when the tenant admin has not provided admin consent to your web API for the scopes you want to use. Hence, the tenant admin needs to provide the admin consent to the scopes for  Web API.